Running Device Window Visible Setting in Android Studio
Every time when I click the run button to open my app on my real android device the Running Device panel is opening. Is there any setting to hide it's visible?
I did remove it from the sidebar but every time it is opening again. The Running Device screen is usefully but it's annoying to have it open every time I click the run button.
Is there any suggestion for this? thanks.


UPDATE
Follow the Mike's suggest. That is fixed my problem.

It sounds like you have device mirroring enabled. It's in general settings: https://i.sstatic.net/oZ6p0.png.

thanks @MikeM. you are right, I unchecked all of them and now the Running Devices screen is not opening when I click the run button (if the physical device connected)
